# Cannot read property 'value' of null if Content-Security-Policy

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

When I use whitelist plugin in cordova 5.1 application I cannot get input text value,I am  getting error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null".Please help me.

I have added my code.

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("loginsubmit").addEventListener("click", validationCheck(),false);

    function validationCheck() {
      alert("name =" +  document.getElementById('username').value);
    }
</script>

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">


</head>
<body>

    <form  method="post" class="login_forms">
        <div class="loginform">
            <div class="user">
                <label class="usericon">UserName:</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" size="20px">
            </div>
            <div class="pass">
                <label class="passicon">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password"  size="20px">
            </div>
                   <div class="submit_btn">

                <input type="button" class="loginsubmit" id="loginsubmit" name="loginsubmit" value="Login">
                <input type="submit" class="logincancel" id="logincancel" value="Cancel">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: document.getElementById('username') could be returning null if it can not find the element 'username'. Does it definitely exist?

Comment: Can you post your content security policy meta tag if you think that's the problem?

Comment: I have added my full  code,meta tag I added is <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to reference the element before it is rendered to the page. That is like trying to eat a taco before you make the taco or it is like calling a person's name before they arrive to your party.

You need to wait for  the element to be rendered. So you need to place the script at the end of the body or call it on document ready or call it on window onload.

The next issue is you are calling `validationCheck`, not making a reference to it

```
document.getElementById("loginsubmit").addEventListener("click", validationCheck(),false);
                                                                               ^^^^
```

needs to be

```
document.getElementById("loginsubmit").addEventListener("click", validationCheck,false);
```

Comment: When I add document.getElementById("loginsubmit").addEventListener("click", validationCheck,false); inside deviceready event I got result. Thank you for your suggestion.